# Bootstrap tables - How to set a left margin from the 2nd column of the table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm a newbie in Front-End development and I'll be glad if you can help me.

I have a bootstrap table and I need that the 2nd column will have a margin-left of 80px fron the 1st column.

I've tried implementing this in the following way but nothing helped:

### HTML:

```
                  <table class="table table-hover modules-table" id="module-list-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Modified</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                                        <td>Mark</td>
                                        <td>Otto</td>
                                        <td>@mdo</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                                        <td>Jacob</td>
                                        <td>Thornton</td>
                                        <td>@fat</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

### CSS:

```
#table-underline {
    border: 1px solid #2baab1;
    margin-top:12px;
}

.modules-table > tbody > tr > th ,.modules-table > tbody > tr > td {
    border-color:#ececef;
}

.modules-table  > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    width:336px;
    margin-left:80px !important;
}
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3hamc4b0/

I've tried find any information about this issue but with no luck.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: First off, you have 5 columns in the first "tr", and 4 in the others. And what column do you want to add the margin to? Name?

Comment: The column I was requested to add 80px margin from left is the 2nd columnd called "Name"

Comment: Okay. Why does it have to be exactly 80px?

Comment: Because it's a demand of my UX designer and my boss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vincent G has mentioned, you shall use `padding`rather than `margin`.
However, you probably should apply it to both header and body :

```
.modules-table tr > *:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

Now, if you didn't have that "specifically 80px" condition, I would have suggested you use a grid instead. Just in case, and for future reference, I have added it in the fiddle.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/3hamc4b0/3/

Answer (score 1):

To make it works, you can use `padding-left` instead of `margin-left` and also adapt the width of the `td`

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/3hamc4b0/1/)

```
.modules-table  > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    width:256px;
    padding-left:80px;
}
```